# c# send post data with javascript field

Tags: c#, javascript, http, post, httpwebresponse

I have such code binded on my button

```
private String readHtmlPage2(string url)
        {

            //setup some variables

            String country = "6";
            String city = "95";
            String lang = "17";
            String wtf = "ctl00$tresc$upPlacowka|ctl00$tresc$cbListaPlacowek";

            //setup some variables end

            String result = "";
            String strPost = "ctl00$tresc$cbListaKrajow=" + country + "&ctl00$tresc$cbListaPlacowek=" + city + "&ctl00$ddlWersjeJezykowe=" + lang + "&ctl00$tresc$ScriptManager1" + wtf;
            StreamWriter myWriter = null;

            HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            objRequest.Method = "POST";
            objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
            objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            try
            {
                myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
                myWriter.Write(strPost);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                myWriter.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr =
               new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();

                // Close and clean up the StreamReader
                sr.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string PostData(string file, string data)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(file);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] EncodedPostParams = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams,
                                             0,
                                             EncodedPostParams.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),
                                           Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            return html;
        }
```

I need to send post data on our page, but main trouble is that form is dynamic, some field look's like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$tresc$cbListaKrajow" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$tresc$cbListaKrajow\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_tresc_cbListaKrajow" style="width:400px;">
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="6">Białoruś</option>

</select>
```

I need to tell my code that it must select this field, that it gives all values... All form you can see on our page: https://by.e-konsulat.gov.pl/default.aspx

I send my data, but nothing happens... how to submit this form? (then i will be redirected)

Comment: You're using a WebRequest to post data. No client side script will be executed for you in that request since there's not browser to run it. So no redirection. It just returns the contents of the html page you requested.

Comment: I really don't understand  what you're trying to do here. Why do you need to call that page from a WebRequest?? Are you trying to collect data from that website? In that case read the option value from the select control that triggrs the redirect and append it to the url id field of the second page...

Comment: @Jeroen i need to do "checker", so i need to do .exe that will do in auto-mode send post query and get result...  not hacking)

Comment: It's not possible like this. Why don't you check by hand? If 1 works, they all work...

Comment: i cant monitor it 24/7... i need automatize... so would you say: what to choose than, that is real?